# Insert statement doesn't check for duplicate values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I am trying to prevent duplicate entries into my sqlite db by using the UNIQUE identifier when creating a table. The information, including the primary key, is inserted via some json data returned from a web service.

Whilst I understand the implications of not using an auto-generated primary key, it is necessary for the business model.

If by chance the web service returns a record which already exists then you would assume that it would not insert the data again, but throw an error. This is not the case.

Does anyone know a way to prevent this from happening?

*Creation statement*

`CREATE TABLE "Data" ("Id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "DataText" TEXT NOT NULL , "CategoryId" INTEGER NOT NULL )`

*Insert code*

```
if (sqlite3_open([[self getDatabaseConnection] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {        
        const char *sql = "INSERT INTO Data (Id, CategoryId, DataText) Values(?, ?, ?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        else
        {
            sqlite3_bind_int64(addStatement, 1, dataId);
            sqlite3_bind_int64(addStatement, 2, categoryId);
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStatement, 3, [dataText UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStatement))
            {
                NSLog(@"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database), nil);
            }
        }
        //Reset the add statement.
        sqlite3_reset(addStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: Did you try creating a sample tuple and reinserting it over and over again? This will help you confirm if you have a DDL problem or if the data isn't being converted properly from the web service.

Comment: That's what originally caused my concern, after calling the request the number fo rows increased although there was no new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a table called PRODUCTS and it contains this value:

```
               ProductID|ProductName
               50|widget
```

ProductID is the primary key.

Unless you have a unique index on [productname] you could insert this record:

```
              60|widget
```

But even if you did not have a unique index on productname, you could not insert any additional records with a productid of 50, no matter what the product's name happened to be, because a row with primary key value of 50 already exists.

ADDENDUM:

Now let's say that you were willing to accept multiple instances of 'widget' but not within the same category.  You could have "roofing widget" and "flooring widget".  In that case, in addition to the primary key unique constraint on your integer id column, you could place a unique constraint on this alternate *composite* key:  (productname, categoryid).

ADDENDUM2:

INTEGER PRIMARY KEY should suffice.  You shouldn't need NOT NULL UNIQUE.  http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Comment: Agree completely. But it's the Id field which requires the constraint. As you can see from the table creation sql, the unique clause should take care of that.

Comment: The ID field requires *a* (not 'the') unique constraint. There can be more than one unique constraint per table. And you must have more than one unique constraint if you wish to prevent multiple instances of 'widget', when you're using an integer primary key and not making the product name itself the primary key.

Comment: I'd add an answer, but sometimes everything has been said already.

Comment: Ok so having removed the `NOT NULL UNIQUE` part of the creation statement the code now throws a constraint failed error, but although there are over 900 records, it only threw the error about 20 times.

Comment: @JLevett:  are you implying that of the 900 rows, many more than 20 are duplicates?

Comment: Not at all. More like after executing the "get data" function the second time, it only fails on about 20 rows, where all 900 should not be inserted again.

Comment: There's more than one table in the sqlite db, and it appears than it doesnt follow the contraint in 2 of them, but it does in the other 2, the 36 errors it threw would indicate to me that 10 failed in one table, and 2 failed in the other (this occured 3 times)

Comment: It turns out that the DataId that was being passed to the insert statement had been converted wrongly from the json data. While you were never to know this, your addendum led me to find the solution. So I shall mark this as the correct answer. Thank you for your help.